# unable to connect external server database

Tags: php, mysql

how to access cpanel database access in godady server using mysql php connectivity
i have tried a lot but last long it gives me

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to
>   MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error:
>   111 in /home/content/q/u/i/quickandkosh/html/searchdata.php on line 6
>   Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 111

Comment: What is your PHP Connection string? You can X-out values.

Comment: Is it sure that remote access is enabled?

Comment: Contact GoDaddy **[(480-505-8877)](http://support.godaddy.com/)** because I doubt they actively participate on StackOverflow. [connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about go daddy but I know some web hosts need a specific path to mysql server. Most us `localhost` but others, such as ipage use a full path through the virtual server. Go into your cpanel at godaddy and then "mysql databases" and it should have a "server" title with address below it  somewhere in the page.

Just to note, you should also be using `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: @Rush did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your host could be wrong, wrong port, a firewall blocked the connection.  So I would double check your connection settings.

Comment: $con = mysql_connect($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], $conf['db_password']) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aTableName", $con);

Comment: is the username and the password the same as the one issued by GoDaddy?

Comment: alternatively, if not using PDO class:  <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password');
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
  mysqli_select_db("databaseName", $con);
  ..
  ..
  ..
  mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Another possibility is to check that port 3306 going outbound is open